# Please change the permissions to 0770 so that the directory

Tags: permissions, directory, owncloud-server

I did everything according to [these instructions on the OwnCloud forum](http://forum.owncloud.org/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=7118)
but I get the error:

> Data directory (`/mnt/usbdrive/owncloud/`) is readable for other users
>   Please change the permissions to 0770 so that the directory cannot be listed by other users.

I gave the permissions like:

```
 chmod 0770 /mnt/usbdrive/owncloud/
```

and I changed my `/etc/fstab`

I used:

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /mnt/usbdrive/owncloud/
```

as well. But I still get that error when going to owncloud

This is what my `/etc/fstab` looks like:

[[image: screenshot of fstab in terminal]

**EDIT:** This error only comes up when I change the data directory. If I keep it the same, I can acces it normally.

Comment: If `/mnt/usbdrive/owncloud/` is on a filesystem like FAT or NTFS that doesn't support Unix-style permissions `chmod` and `chown` don't work and you have to set the permissions using mount options. Please add the content of your `/etc/fstab` to your question.

Comment: @FlorianDiesch see my edit

Comment: To separate  fs problem from an owncould problem, how does it work when you put your owncloud data in /var/owncoud (for instance)

Comment: @Emmanuel You mean the standard data directory? It gives me a log in screen. When I use the hdd directory, it gives me that error.

Comment: Maybe your chown/chmod is not working or it check also that the parent directory is not too permissive, what shows the command `ls -ld /mnt/usbdrive/owncloud   /mnt/usbdrive`

Comment: @Emmanuel 

drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 65536 nov 22 10:51 /mnt/usbdrive

drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4096 nov 21 16:43 /mnt/usbdrive/owncloud

Comment: have you tried "chmod 0770 /mnt/usbdrive/owncloud/ -R" ??

Comment: @Sushantp606 I did.

Comment: sorry I gave answer who was wrong, I deleted. did you remount your usb drive sinc you changed the fstab ?

Comment: @Emmanuel yes I did

Comment: I reproduce your problem, see my answer.

Comment: @Emmanuel I'll try it tomorrow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the inputs you provided,  you have to change your mount options in `/etc/fstab`.

```
quiet,defaults,permissions,locale=en_US.utf8
```

Don't use the `umask` option; it seems that the mount.ntfs-3g manpage is false where it claims that mask will apply to newer files. All the ".mask" options apply also to already *existing* files.

With `umask=0` all your files get `rwxrwxrwx` rights.

Comment: Okay now you know what, I have no idea if this fixed it. I did 2 things before rebooting my raspberry. Your fix and chmod a+r /mnt/usbdrive/. Vote up anyway

Comment: @Loko I was  wrong when I tested I made a sysntax error to the permissions option. Your problem was the umask=0 populating rights to all you file. I rewrote my answer. Now all is working.

Answer (score 1):

I *assume* you're new to using Linux commands. In Linux, there is a **SuperUser** named **Root** which by default is locked (you can unlock it though). But you can still run programs with *root-level privileges*. This is where [`sudo`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo) comes in - it allows *authorized users* to run certain programs as *Root*. And you'll find yourself using *sudo* very often while performing the administrative tasks.

[Changing *file mode bits* and *ownership*](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions) in `/mnt` directory will require root privileges. So if you haven't already done this, run the commands with *sudo* as:

```
sudo chmod 0770 /mnt/usbdrive/owncloud/
sudo chown www-data:www-data /mnt/usbdrive/owncloud/
```

Answer (score 0):

1. First find the `uid` (user id) and `gid` (group id) for your mount (do a `grep` in `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group`).
2. Then add an entry in `/etc/fstab`

**/etc/fstab**

```
/dev/sda1 /mnt/usbdrive ntfs-3g  quiet,locale=en_US.utf8,uid=1001,gid=33,dmode=770,fmode=660,comment=systemd.automount 0 0
```

EDIT: quite to quiet

Comment: I think that should be "quiet", not "quite"